# Why is there no IO monad transformer in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Recently I studied monad transformers in Haskell. And I became very curious why there is no `IOT` monad transformer. For example, I can add `IORef` environment to `IO` monad like this

`type IORefEnv s = ReaderT (IORef s) IO`

But why can't I add `IO` effect to my environment in a similar way?

`type IOReader r a = IOT (Reader r) a`

Comment: Hm. I'm actually not sure the marked question is a duplicate. The answer there shows why one (completely plausible, reasonable guess for an) implementation of `IOT` doesn't work, but not why it can't be done in general.